# partial derivative with absolute value

Tags: partial-derivative

I have a simple question about the partial derivative of a function including an absolute value.
I am reading a book and there is a summation:

$$
A = β\sum_\textbf{x} ||\textbf{x}||^n r(\textbf{x})$$
where $n \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ and $\textbf{x} = (x_0, x_1, ... , x_{M−1})^T$.
My question is: Can I treat the elements $||\textbf{x}||^n$ from summation as a constant during the partial derivative in relation to $r(\textbf{x})$, obtaining: 
$$\frac{\partial  A(\textbf{x})}{\partial r(\textbf{x})} = β||\textbf{x}||^n$$?

Answer (score 2):

If you define the function as $ H(x, y) = \beta \|x\| y$, then $A(x) = H(x, r(x))$ and

$$\partial_{r(x)}H(\|x\|, r(x)) = \beta \|x\|$$
also, you need to be carefull with the  sum.
If it is  on a finite set then

$$\frac{\partial  A(x)}{\partial r(\textbf{x})} = β\sum_x||\textbf{x}||^n$$

Don't forget  to remember that $$\frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x} = \sum_x \partial_{x}H(\|x\|, r(x))  + \partial_{r(x)}H(\|x\|, r(x)) $$

Comment: +! for the line "Don't forget to remember" :-)

Comment: I've changed the definition to represent exactly what I saw in this book. Sorry if the first time I was not precise, but the answer does not contain the summation